# Show/Hide FileExplorer in Access Form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I've been trying to use a combobox to show/hide a PDF viewer that I've added into a MS Access form.

When I use the form_current event, then the form only updates when I move between the data entries. When I use the afterupdate event, the same code does nothing at all.

Does anyone have a fix? The code I have used is below, which I have tried both the AfterUpdate event for the Browser and the Form_Current event for the whole form

```
Private Sub PDFT900_AfterUpdate() / Private Sub Form_Current()

Dim ESNComb As String
ESNComb = Me.ESNCombo.Column(1)

 If ESNComb Like "9????" Then
   Me.PDFT900.Visible = True
 Else
   Me.PDFT900.Visible = False
    
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want the action to react to a Combo-box value change, use the combo-box's `AfterUpdate` event handler.

Comment: That's managed to hide/not hide the box. Thank you. The file explorer now does not display the file though and is now just a blank box. Might you have any suggestions?

Comment: Please point out where in the question and/or in the code do you refer to a file explorer? If you don't, I'd suggest you post a new question, and state what have tried, what are the results, and how are they different from what you've planed and/or expected.

Comment: Why are you using ComboBox's Column property? Does the comboBox contain a multi-column list? Doesn't column 0 update the Text property after a change event?

Comment: Why are you using a wildcard, "9???", expression match? Are all of the PDF items in the list 4 characters long and prepended with "9"?

Answer (score 1):

In the code below, I'm hiding and showing the Adobe PDF Reader ActiveX control named, "AcroPDF0". Since the *Like* operator returns true on an expression match and false on a mismatch or no match, it serves as a simple boolean switch for the visible property. I've used the **(*)** wild card instead of **(?)**. It works *{shrug}*. See demonstration images below.

```
Private Sub ESNCombo_AfterUpdate()
   'AcroPDF0.Visible = ESNCombo.Text Like "P*"
    AcroPDF0.Visible = ESNCombo.Column(0) Like "P*"
    AcroPDF0.src = acroPDFOSrc
End Sub
```

**ComboBox List Items**
[image]

**"File Browser" Selected in ComboBox**
[image]

Toggled ComboBox back to "PDFT900"
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! Its a strange one, I can get the activex window to show/hide no problem now thanks to Marlans comment. I now however want to be able to flick through records and the activex control box does not show/hide for the previous records, unless I make an edit to the record. Even then, when I make the edit and it shows up again, the activex control box remains blank and does not display the PDF, just gives me the outline...

Comment: Yeah, ActiveX controls can be flaky, depending on how they're designed, and how much of the full program's APIs and features they expose. Note in the example above that I had to refresh the source document of the Adobe ActiveX control. I did so, because it was blank after toggling visibility on and off. Of course, it would start at the beginning of the document, instead of remember the location.

I recommend closely examining the properties and methods of your control, using a different control, or using an opensource PDF viewer to create your own ActiveX control.